# Recovering lost cloud savegames after changing the HDD on x360

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

Recently I changed my HDD drive, so I manually moved all my savegame files to the cloud. I switched the disks, installed Forza Horizon, ran it and on storage selection prompt I chose the cloud. And that's it, it has created a new savegame, clearing ALL my progress.

I can't explain how mad I am right now. Is there any way to get those saves back? Like file version history on the servers or maybe I did something wrong when moving the files?

Comment: Moved or copied?

Comment: @Brok3n Moved, since the console didn't allow me to copy savegames. It's a shame that I didn't make myself a backup really. Although I've got cloud cache file on the old drive, so I'm thinking about injecting it to the new drive.

Comment: Personally, this is a case where I would contact Microsoft support. If you moved the files and they are not on the service, Microsoft needs to troubleshoot the issue.